# Cannot insert post array in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, insert

I'm trying to insert a POST array consisting in 8 fields to a mysql table of 8 columns, but I'm getting this error when submitting the form:

> Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

When I search this error says the data passed doesn't fit in the column count of the database table, but the table has 8 columns. What I'm doing wrong?

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">

Nombre: <input type="text" name="data[]">
Apellido: <input type="text" name="data[]"></br>
Direccion: <input type="text" name="data[]"></br>
Telefono: <input type="text" name="data[]">
Telefono 2: <input type="text" name="data[]"></br>
Email: <input type="text" name="data[]"></br>
Edad: <input type="text" name="data[]"></br>
Foto: <input type="text" name="data[]"> 
<input type="submit">

</form>

<?php

$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con){  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }


mysql_select_db("ag_online", $con);

foreach($_POST['data'] as $d ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
    mysql_query( $sql ); 
}


if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}   
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the table has 8 columns, you cannot use:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
```

directly.

You have to specify which columns you are inserting:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (col1, col2) VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
```

**Update**
When you using

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $d ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
    mysql_query( $sql ); 
}
```

is the same as using

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $d ){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto)  VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
    mysql_query( $sql ); 
}
```

as you say in the comments.

However, as you are looping on `$_POST['data']`, it will come to something like:

first loop:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto)  VALUES ('', 'FIRST_VALUE');";
```

first loop:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto)  VALUES ('', 'SECOND_VALUE');";
```

that is, you will try to insert 2 values after saying you will give 8.

You can use the following to populate a variable `$info` and then do an unique `insert`:

```
$info=implode(",", $_POST['data']);
$info="\"".implode("\",\"", $_POST['data'])."\""; //<--- updated answer, to have all items "wrapped"
```

and then

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto)  VALUES ('', $info);";
```

Comment: I've tried:  foreach($_POST['datos'] as $d ){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `contactos` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto) VALUES ('', '".$d."');";
        mysql_query( $sql ); 
 }

Comment: Can you show a `print_r($_POST['datos']);` this way we can see what can be happening

Comment: how are you going to insert nombre, apellida, direccion, telefono,  etc.. with values ('', '', 'id'), it DOES NOT match again. As @zipser said you have to explicively tell which column you are going to insert in. If you are inserting 2 values, then only 2 columns

Comment: sure: Array ( [0] => Name [1] => LastName [2] => Address [3] => 123 [4] => 456 [5] => email@mail.com [6] => 25 [7] => photo )

Comment: OK so you have to follow what @RoyalBg is telling you: insert as many fields as you indicate on `INSERT INTO contacts (field1, field2, ...) VALUES ...`.

Comment: Royal Bg: I've already specified to which columns insert the values but i get the same error...

Comment: But if you use foreach, each time you will insert 2 values while the table has 8 fields.

Comment: how i'm inserting 2 values if i specified the 8 values here??: $sql = "INSERT INTO `contactos` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto) VALUES ('', '".$d."');";

Comment: @zipser Thanks, i still don't understand why it will loop only 2 times?. Now i'm trying to do what you suggest but i get the same error:  `code` foreach($_POST['datos'] as $d ){
  $info = $d ;
 }
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `contactos` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto) VALUES ('', '".$info."');";
        mysql_query( $sql ); `code`

Comment: i think the problem is in this part?: VALUES ('', '".$info."');";  What i should write there to insert the 8 fields that the array has?

Comment: thank you, i get a sql sintax error now, can you check if the sql you wrote is correct?, i think we're close

Comment: Print `$sql` and check it!

Comment: i've done it. It seems it was adding an extra column with this: ('', $info) But when i removed '' and leave ($info) i get the same error... any clues

Comment: INSERT INTO `contactos` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto) VALUES ('', Name,LastName,Address,1,2,email,25,photo)Error: Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list'

Comment: So you only need to use: `$sql = "INSERT INTO contacts (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto)  VALUES ($info);";`

Comment: I told you i've already tried that, but i'm getting the same error: INSERT INTO `contactos` (Nombre, Apellido, Direccion, Telefono, Telefono2, Email, Edad, Foto) VALUES (Name,LastName,Address,1,2,email,25,photo);Error: Unknown column 'Name' in 'field list

Comment: Ah ok you need to wrap each value within quotes

Comment: If i do this: VALUES ('$info');"; i get the first error: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: No, you have to wrap each one of the items to be inserted: see my updated answer.

Comment: There was an error on my answer. I somehow have the feeling I am writing all the code...

Comment: what is your problem?, i though this was a website where you can get help and learn, i'm learning php

Comment: The problem is that we help, not work for you. You come with a doubt and we try to solve the specific problem.

Comment: i had a lot of doubts since i'm new in php

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to have each one in column, then you might want to consider this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `contacts` VALUES ('";
foreach($_POST['data'] as $d ){
 $sql .= $d."','";
}
 $sql = substr_replace($sql, "", -2);
 $sql .= ");";
 mysql_query( $sql );
```

Comment: It will give trailing comma + apostrophe which will generate error, You need removal of last comma + apostrophe outside loop.

Comment: i'm getting this error with that code: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FOREACH in C:\wamp\www\ABM 1\index.php on line 29

Comment: Add semi colon after first line